# I'm having trouble with a Python Snake game using curses

Tags: python, curses

Update:
I have fixed some parts of my code and now the snake game starts up :)
Its only when the snake eats the food that the score doesn't go up and the food does not appear in a random location

The guide that I have been using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_npdRYD4K0

```
snake = [(4, 12), (4, 11), (4, 10)]
food = [10, 30]

stdscr.addch(food[0], food[1], '%')

# game code or game logic

ESC = 27
key = KEY_RIGHT

score = 0

while key != ESC:
    
    stdscr.addstr(0, 2, 'Score ' + str(score) + ' ') 
    stdscr.timeout(150 - (len(snake))//5 + len(snake)//10 % 120)    
    
    prevKey = key
    event = stdscr.getch()                                          
    key = event if event != -1 else prevKey
    
    if key not in [KEY_LEFT, KEY_DOWN, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_UP, ESC]:    
        key = prevKey
        
    y = snake[0][0]                                            
    x = snake[0][1]                                             
    
    if key == KEY_UP:
        y -= 1
    if key == KEY_LEFT:
        x -= 1
    if key == KEY_RIGHT:
        x += 1
    if key == KEY_DOWN:
        y += 1
        
    snake.insert(0, (y, x))
    
    # The snek will go through the boundaries, and out to the other side
    if y == 0: y = 18
    if y == 19: y = 1
    if x == 0: x = 58
    if x == 59: x = 1
    
    # if the snek hits itself it will break the program
    if snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        print("You hit yourself...")
        break
    
    if snake[0] == food:

        score += 1
        food = ()
        while food == ():
            food = (randint(1, 18), randint(1, 58))
            if food in snake:
                food = ()
        stdscr.addch(food[0], food[1], '%')
    else:
        last = snake.pop()
        stdscr.addch(last[0], last[1], ' ')
    stdscr.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], '*')

curses.endwin()
print("\nYour final score: %s" % score)
```

Comment: # if the snek hits itself it will break the program

here put a print statement if it breaks so you can check if this is the issue

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for commenting but it is not the issue